# Bash variable changes when inside quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I'm trying to grab the first file matching a pattern and use that in a statement. Using the same steps as found in [How can I get the first match from wildcard expansion?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156205/how-can-i-get-the-first-match-from-wildcard-expansion#) I wrote the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=("*.sql")
firstfile=${files[0]}
echo $firstfile
echo "The first file is $firstfile"
```

When I run this, the output is:

> sqlfile.sql
>
> The first file is *.sql

Why does the value of `$firstfile` change based on the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the quotes in the files line, which leaves:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=(*.sql)
firstfile=${files[0]}
echo $firstfile
echo "The first file is $firstfile"
```

Answer (score 4):

The last line prints what really is in $firstfile.

The first echo expands $firstfile via the filesystem as you did not use double quotes.